# How to install gearman extension on MAMP

Tags: mamp, php-extension, pecl, gearman

Has anyone ever tried and succeeded to install gearman extension on MAMP?
I am trying to do it on MAMP 2.x on a MAC OS X 10.6.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally made it!

Here is how:
I had to install "libevent" first,
then to install "libgearman",
and finally the extension

I I moved the gearman.so to the extensions directory of MAMP and then I added the extension in the php.ini

Answer (score 8):

You can install the server with homebrew

```
brew install gearman
```

Then download the PECL package here http://pecl.php.net/package/gearman and compile it

```
tar xzf gearman-X.Y.tgz
cd gearman-X.Y
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then copy/paste the gearman.so from your default extensions folder (for me /usr/lib/php/extensions/) to your MAMP extensions folder (eg. /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-xxxxx/)

Finally add

```
extension="gearman.so"
```

to your MAMP php.ini (/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini)

Restart apache and you're done