# How to install Gearman on MAMP (OSX)

Tags: php-7, gearman, mamp-pro

I'm trying to install and run Gearman on my local env using MAMP pro. Mainly I followed this guide [How to install gearman extension on MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705925/how-to-install-gearman-extension-on-mamp) but for some reason this won't work for me.

Exact steps:

1. brew install gearman
2. Downloaded the PECL package (http://pecl.php.net/package/gearman) and compiled it using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705925/how-to-install-gearman-extension-on-mamp)
3. tar xzf gearman-X.Y.tgz
4. cd gearman-X.Y
5. phpize
6. ./configure
7. make
8. sudo make install ([before I could successfully run this I had to turn off the rootless in osx](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-turn-off-the-rootless-in-OS-X-El-Capitan-10-11?share=1))
9. I added extension="gearman.so" to the php.ini file of my active php version
10. Restarted apache, MAMP, even my PC

After all these steps I added phpinfo() to one of my files in order to check if the extension was installed successfully, but Gearman doesn't show up in the list. When I try to run a gearman function I get a fatal error saying "Call to undefined function gearman_version()" for example.

What am I missing here?

Secondly, I have to get the backend running, in the guides I saw and followed I saw lot's of references to [Gearmand](https://github.com/gearman/gearmand) which is responsible for getting the server & workers running. But after following these guides I keep getting "command gearmand" not found.

So I'm looking for guidance or a full blown tutorial to get this working with MAMP. Suggestions/tips/tutorials are all welcome!

Thanks!

Joren

Comment: Asking for links to tutorials, etc. is off-topic for SO. So you can only really ask for specific guidance.

Comment: Did you find a solution? have the same problem

Comment: @Bookin I didn't